# VBA CSng(string) wrong format

Tags: vba, ms-access

I read in a node from a xml file and try to parse one of its attributes to a single.

```
Dim x_coord_single As Single
Dim x_coord_string As String
x_coord_string = node.Attributes.getNamedItem("x_coord").Text
x_coord_single = CSng(x_coord_string )
```

After i assign `x_coord_string` it equals `"9.0647"`
But the `CSng` function returns `90647`

I would expect `x_coord_single` to be `9.0647`.

I tried `CSng("9.0647")` directly but it's the same outcome.

Any suggestions on why it is not?
I'm working with MS Access 2010 if it affects this anyhow.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do? Convert a String to Integer? Why you don't declare your variable as `Integer` instead as `String`?

Comment: @David G. because i read it in from a xml node attribute, it returns me a string, but i need this to be a single

Comment: Could this be a regional settings issue? What does `CSng("9,0647")` return? Some regions use `,` for the decimal separator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Public Function fnStrChangeCommas(ByVal myValue As Variant) As String
    fnStrChangeCommas = Replace(CStr(myValue), ".", ",")
End Function

x_coord_single = CSng(fnStrChangeCommas(x_coord_string ))
```

It should work, because your language regional settings use `,` as a decimal separator and the VBEditor uses the `.`.

---

To see the separators your system is using in VBA, run the following code:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print "Decimal separator: "; Application.DecimalSeparator
    Debug.Print "Thousands separator: "; Application.ThousandsSeparator

End Sub
```

If it returns this:

```
Decimal separator: ,
Thousands separator: .
```

Then you may consider using the `fnStrChangeCommas` function.

Comment: well it was the opposite case, but this gave me the right direction, thanks

Comment: @Pio - you mean that the function is opposite or the explanation?

Comment: the replace function, i needed to do `Replace(x_coord_string, ".", ",")`

Comment: @pio - true, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The simple and universal method is to use *Val*:

```
x_coord_single = CSng(Val(x_coord_string))
```