# Replace expression doesn't work in VBA with "."

Tags: excel, vba

I need to replace `","` with `"."` using `Replace` expression.

For example I have : `115,147058823529`

It doesn't work for `"."` or any other characters

```
Range("K" & rw).Value = Replace(Range("K" & rw).Value, ",", ".")
```

Result: `115,147058823529`

While it works perfectly for `".."`

```
Range("K" & rw).Value = Replace(Range("K" & rw).Value, ",", "..")
```

Result: `115..147058823529`

I couldn't find any explanation for that.
I want to make it run for `"."`

The number format s general and I don't want to mess with that.

I have even tried replacing `","` by `"m."` which gives : `115m.147058823529`
Then replacing `m` by `""` and that gives : `115.147058823529` .. which is really weird

Comment: What regional settings are you using? German?

Comment: @Vityata That's French

Comment: Quite the same. The problem is not in VBA itself, it is in the Excel settings.

Comment: Is there a way to turn around this

Comment: I was thinking to replace with ".m" then replace the "m" with "" . But it' messy and I don't like it

Comment: I think you need to format the cell as a text: Right click on the cell -> Cell Format -> Choose "Text"

Comment: @aekbj - feel free to

Comment: try `\.` insteadof `.`

Comment: @Sigrist - this does not work for VBA.

Comment: @NaderNagazi that worked, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is in the regional settings and the decimal separator that you are using. The French/German decimal separator is a comma and the US one is a dot.

VBA, on the other hand uses only dot as a decimal separator. Thus, VBA reads the number with a comma and converts it internally with a dot. Then it is not finding any comma inside.

---

The `Replace()` itself works quite ok:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim someString As String
    someString = "115,147058823529"
    someString = Replace(someString, ",", ".")

    MsgBox someString

End Sub
```

Additional information:

- [VBA CSng(string) wrong format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933185/vba-csngstring-wrong-format/46933316#46933316)

Comment: I have tried `Range("K" & rw).Value = Replace(CStr(Range("K" & rw).Value), ",", ".")`But it gives the same result

Comment: @aekbj - yes, this is because there is no comma in your cell, although you are seeing it. VBA sees a dot. If you use the suggestion of  "Nader Nagazi" from the comments and convert the cell to `Text` it would work. But it would not be a number any more.